# Calling asp.net ajax function from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to call asp.net ajax method from javascript function using the following way

the below function is declared in 'Common.js' file

```
function CheckValidityofId(lookupFunction,fromdate,Id) {
  
   //FormUI is new ascx.cs file having mehtod CheckValidity
   lookupFunction='FormUI.CheckValidity';

    callback = function(response) {
    
        if (response.error) {
            alert(response.error);
        }
        else {
            if (response.value =="NotAssociated")
            {
            document.getElementById(MessageID).innerText="Number is not associated";
            }
            else
            {
            document.getElementById(MessageID).innerText="This is NOT eligible";
            }
        }
    }
    if (fromdate.length > 0 && Id.length >0) {
        eval(lookupFunction + "('" + fromdate + "','" + Id + ")");
    }
    return false;
}
```

I am trying to call 'CheckValidity' method declared in FormUI.ascx.cs.

```
public partial class FormUI : UIView
{
    [Ajax.AjaxMethod()]
    public string CheckValidity(string FromDate, string Id)
    {
      // logic goes here
    }
}
```

'CheckValidity' is not getting triggered from the JavaScript.
Please let me know how to correct the script to call Ajax method in ascx.cs file.